# find out if a id has certain text and then change it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to something like this

```
if($('#ctl00_lblNoResults').text('Please select')){
$('.otherprop').text('Thanks')
}
else {
$('.otherprop').text('No Thanks')
}
```

So i have a layer like so

```
<div id="ctl00_lblNoResults">Don't select</div>
```

And another bit of text

```
<div class="otherprop">No Thanks</div>
```

I need to change the text of "otherprop" if "ctl00_lblNoResults" equals this

```
<div id="ctl00_lblNoResults">Please select</div>
```

to

```
<div class="otherprop">Thanks</div>
```

So desired results are

```
<div id="ctl00_lblNoResults">Don't select</div>
<div class="otherprop">No Thanks</div>
```

or

```
<div id="ctl00_lblNoResults">Please select</div>
<div class="otherprop">Thanks</div>
```

Hope this makes sense

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($('#ctl00_lblNoResults').text() == 'Please select')
$('.otherprop').text('Thanks')
}
else {
$('.otherprop').text('No Thanks')
}
```

should do it

the if-rule you stated sets the text already, after which it will return true if it was successful (probably false if the id doesn't exist)

Answer (score 0):

First, what you have should work.  All you could do is maybe use a conditional statement when setting [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to keep it pretty clean (to me, do what's best for your maintaining it of course), like this:

```
$('.otherprop').text(
  $('#ctl00_lblNoResults').text() == 'Please select' ? 'Thanks' : 'No Thanks';
);
```

Comment: So unfair, hardcore users always beat me by giving a better answer :P

Comment: @Litso - *Anyone* can give "better" answers than anyone else (though that's subjective in and of itself), as long as they put in the effort :)  I've been outdone by very low rep users many, *many* times, lots of tremendously intelligent people here, and rep isn't an indication of that, just your site participation thus far :)

Comment: @Litso - I just don't want to see newer or less active users discouraged is all, *most* of the people posting, new or not provide great content, don't want to see that stop or slow down any :)

Comment: it only encourages me to give more answers, read more better answers, and become smarter overall. don't worry :P